# Gupshup - multiple messages delay feature not working

Tags: gupshup

I've tried to implement a delay feature on my bot to display multiple messages one after the other. The delay feature is displaying in my Flow Bot Builder diagram, but when I test in the conversation tester, and proxy bot on Messenger, the delay doesn't actually happen - all the messages display at once.

I have added the delay code in the IDE to the default.scr file:

```
[main]
   label_dych:Hi! I'm delay-bot and I'm here to help you with any questions you have.:continue
     ((delay 2000))
       label_gthk:I'll never need to take any personal or financial information from you, so as we chat please don't tell me any!:continue
         ((delay 1000))
           label_ylbn:{"name":"quickreply","type":"quick_reply","alias":"What can I help you with?","msgid":"117af569-5188-ff7e-9b48-8c553c2f36cb","content":{"type":"text","text":"What can I help you with?"},"options":[{"type":"text","title":"My Page","iconurl":"","id":"ac49ad32-c9bc-469f-2152-c7c842bad8ea","isDuplicate":false,"name":"user"},{"type":"text","title":"Team Spaces","iconurl":"","id":"8a2017ac-2fc3-0901-be8d-1fad5a2dba12","isDuplicate":false,"name":"user"},{"type":"text","title":"Offline Support","iconurl":"","id":"70861407-e706-17a3-207b-c43958fde83e","isDuplicate":false,"name":"user"},{"type":"text","title":"Something else","iconurl":"","id":"d3f7b6b4-e70a-098d-dde9-1da3e8cc08dc","isDuplicate":false,"name":"user"}]}
```

I've also added the options.apikey line of code to the index.js file as instructed to do here: https://www.gupshup.io/developer/docs/bot-platform/guide/sending-multiple-messages-botscript

```
function ScriptHandler(context, event){
    var options = Object.assign({}, scr_config);
    options.current_dir = __dirname;
    //options.default_message = "Sorry Some Error Occurred.";
    // You can add any start point by just mentioning the 
<script_file_name>.<section_name>
    // options.start_section = "default.main";
    options.success = function(opm){
        context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(opm));
    };
    options.error = function(err) {
        console.log(err.stack);
        context.sendResponse(options.default_message);
    };
    botScriptExecutor.execute(options, event, context);
    options.apikey = "1mbccef47ab24dacad3f99557cb35643";
}
```

Is there any obvious reason why the delay effect wouldn't be working in between messages? I've used the apikey that is displayed for my gupshup account when I click the logo in the top right.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed the API key after the scripting tool execute function is called. Place the API Key anywhere before the `botScriptExecutor.execute` and the delay should work.

Also, the timing of the delay is in milliseconds.

Sample:

```
function ScriptHandler(context, event){
var options = Object.assign({}, scr_config);
options.current_dir = __dirname;
//options.default_message = "Sorry Some Error Occurred.";
options.apikey = "1mbccef47ab24dacad3f99557cb35643";
// You can add any start point by just mentioning the 
<script_file_name>.<section_name>
// options.start_section = "default.main";
options.success = function(opm){
    context.sendResponse(JSON.stringify(opm));
};
options.error = function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
    context.sendResponse(options.default_message);
};
botScriptExecutor.execute(options, event, context);
```

}